# Add left margin to recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In Android, suppose I have a `RecyclerView` with a list of cells, which are represented as `LinearLayout`, my question is, how can I add a left margin and right margin to this **whole RecyclerView** itself so that each cell also has a left and right margin? I would like a better way compared to doing it in the cell class so I am wondering if i can just add left and right margins to a `RecyclerView` itself?

Comment: you add the margins to the item's layout, then all the items in the list will have the margins

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yeah but that doesnt seem too ideal

Comment: You add two margins in one place; what would me more ideal?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo, the recyclerview can have two types of cells, then i have to add a margin in both those items rather than the whole recyclerview.

Comment: just add the margins to the recycler view like suggested on the answer below

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings  I suggest that in the future you add all the relevant code to your question. Right now we don't see what you have, and we don't see what you're trying to achieve and failing.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file for the layout, just add margins to the RecyclerView itself.

```
<RecyclerView
   marginStart = "20dp"
   marginEnd = "20dp"
/>
```